# Drupal contact form validation and alert not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I am trying to make a Drupal website. My issue is that - I am not getting any alert/notification after contact form submission.

The page redirects to the Home page. The Form is working fine as I can receive the mail for the contact form but It never shows any success/fail alert.

Moreover, If the required fields are left empty and the form is submitted, then the contact page only reload.

This happens only when I am using `Venture` theme.

I want alerts for required fields, success and fail notifications.

I am using `Drupal 7.40`.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: include your ajax callback for the form.